# Custom container range-based iteration

Tags: c++, containers

I have a custom container which I want to use in a ranged-based for loop. The container is somewhat based on a vector, like this:

```
template<typename T>
class IDMap
{
private:
    struct Item {
        uint16_t mVersion;
        T mItem;

        template <typename... Arguments>
        Item(uint16_t version, Arguments&&... args) : mVersion(version), mItem(args...)
        {
        }
    };


public:
    typedef uint32_t ItemID;

    template <typename... Arguments>
    ItemID AddItem(Arguments&&... args);

    void MarkAsFree(const ItemID id);

    T& GetItem(const ItemID id);

    T* TryGetItem(const ItemID id);

    void Clear();


private:
    std::vector<Item> mItems;
    std::vector<uint16_t> mFreeIndices;
};
```

I want to iterate the `mItems` vector, but only return the `mItem` member rather than the entire `Item` struct. Is there any easy/elegant way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `mItem(args...)`, write `mItem(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)` for *"perfect forwarding"*. And I guess you have similar logic in the implementation of `AddItem`.

Comment: What is the difference? Both versions seem to compile and run fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide a `begin` and `end` function, both returning a corresponding iterator, which itself implements operators `++`, `!=` and `*`. The `begin` and `end` functions can be free-standing or as members.

Start with implementing an iterator which has the behavior you want. You can implement it as a wrapper around a `std::vector::iterator` to save most of the "core" work.

*The following is untested code*

Basically, inside class IDMap, add:

```
class ItemIterator {
    // based on vector iterator
    std::vector<Item>::iterator i;
public:
    ItemIterator(std::vector<Item>::iterator i) : i(i) {}

    // incrementing
    ItemIterator & operator ++() { ++i; return *this; }
    ItemIterator operator ++(int) { const_iterator old(*this); ++(*this); return old; }

    // comparison
    bool operator!=(const ItemIterator &o) const { return i != o.i; }

    // dereferencing
    const T & operator*() const { return i->mItem; }
};

using iterator = ItemIterator;
using value_type = T;

ItemIterator begin() const { return ItemIterator(mItems.begin()); }
ItemIterator end()   const { return ItemIterator(mItems.end()  ); }
```

If you ever want to support multiple kinds of "special iteration" over your IDMap, like for example also over the indices, or over the "whole" `Item`s, you should wrap everything above in another adaptor. This adaptor can then be accessed with a member method, like `.items()`.

Brief example:

```
class IDMap {
    // (your code)

public:
    struct ItemsAdaptor {
        // (insert above iterator definition + usings)

        ItemsAdaptor(std::vector<Item>::iterator b,
                     std::vector<Item>::iterator e)
            : b{b}, e{e}
        {}

        ItemIterator begin() const { return b; }
        ItemIterator end()   const { return e; }

    private:
        ItemIterator b, e;
    };

    ItemsAdaptor items() const {
        return ItemsAdaptor(mItems.begin(), mItems.end());
    }
};
```

Then, you can write:

```
IDMap<int> map = ...;

for (int i : map.items()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the range-based for to work for your container, you have to provide *begin* and *end* functions that return forward iterators.

```
typedef std::vector<Item>::iterator iterator;
typedef std::vector<Item>::const_iterator const_iterator;
iterator begin()
{
   return mItems.begin();
}
const_iterator begin() const;
{
   return mItems.begin();
}
//also add end functions, and viola.
```

This will return the whole item struct. If you have to only return mItem, you'll have to write your own iterator adaptor and use it instead of vector's.

Comment: I want the later - how do I write my own iterator adaptor? And how can I keep it to a 'minimum'?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan See my answer for that.